# Is there any point in delaying restart?

Tags: trimps

I'm not 100% certain on how it works but I believe that on completing level 30 you get rewarded with 30 helium which when you restart you can spend on upgrades.

I believe that I was also presented with an option to continue and I could restart later. Is that right?

If so, what is the point in continuing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you unlock the Portal (by defeating the boss - "Mega blimp" of the map "Dimension of Anger"), it also mentions that you can now gain helium by killing "regular blimps", which means you get helium by completing any subsequent zones. You get the map by defeating the boss of Zone 20.